# Transform array of objects to nested objects using Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I am a newbie so pardon me if I ask a naive question.

I have an array of objects

```
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}]
```

and I want to convert it to this form using ramda:

```
const obj = {1 : {id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, 5: {id: 5, name: 'John'}, 3: {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}}
```

Can anyone please help?

**Other Conceptual Questions:**

1. I want to convert nested array of objects to this form because that way searching a `name` will be quick if `id` is given. Is this the right approach?
2. Is there any other efficient way performance wise that can make the search in array quicker?

Thanks

Comment: Why is `John`'s `id` 2 in input, but 5 in expected output? a typo, or some logic behind?

Comment: a typo.. corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ramda's R.indexBy:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}]

const result = R.indexBy(R.prop('id'))(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> I want to convert nested array of objects to this form because that
> way searching a name will be quick if id is given. Is this the right
> approach?

Getting an item from array is usually O(n). Getting an item from an object (dictionary), by the property is indexed by is O(1), so object wins... if you want to get the name by the `id`. However, if you are looking for an object by name, you should index by the `name` property. In addition, are you going to look for exact names? or names that contain something. If the search is for a part of name, then you'll still need to iterate everything O(n), and array should be fine as well.

> Is there any other efficient way performance wise that can make the
> search in array quicker?

It actually depends on how you are going to search, and the amount of items you are going to search through, if you are under about 50,000 and searching hy `id` - an object or a Map would be fine, by part of a name - an array would be ok. However, don't try to optimize before you actually have a problem, you profile it, and find that the search is to blame.

Comment: @newbie: please take the last sentence to heart: "However, don't try to optimize before you actually have a problem, you profile it, and find that the search is to blame."  Depending upon the size of your array, a `find` on the array may be plenty fast enough; there is a good chance that this is premature optimization.

Comment: @ScottSauyet if I have 2000 objects in an array. Should I go for changing the array of objects to nested objects?

Comment: @newbie: Have you tested the simplest thing, `arr.find(({id}) => id == query)`?  Is it fast enough for your needs?  If it is, then I wouldn't bother doing any optimization.  My guess is that for 2000 objects, it will be plenty fast, unless you're doing this inside a tight loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without ramda, you could use build-in [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with a mapping of `id` and object.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, { id: 2, name: 'John' }, { id: 3, name: 'Peter' }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(o => [o.id, o]));

console.log(object[2].name);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please also answer the conceptual questions? :)

Comment: @newbie, do you have an id and want to search for a name? or do you have only a name and want the object/id?

Comment: I have an id and I want to get the name

Comment: @newbie, just take the `id` as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) and then `name` propery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here for better performance.

```
const map = new Map();
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}]

for(const {id, name} of arr){
  map.set(id, name);
}

//check id exists 
map.has(1)  // true
//get person's name
map.get(1) //"Pete"
```

Comment: Map also preserves the original order.

Comment: Is it better than converting it to json based nested object (what I am asking in question)?

Comment: I believe it's more scalable approach. Let's say if you want to add another name, you can just do it with `map.set(id, name)`

Answer (score -1):

You could try a filter - this leaves the original array intact and returns a new array with the matches:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}]


let filtered = arr.filter(a => a.id == 1);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Note that your output is totally different from expected output in OP

Comment: The requirement was that he wanted to search for a name within the original array and the only solution he had was to convert the array into a different format.  My suggestion is a simple filter

Comment: OP explicitly provides expected output: "and I want to convert it to this form using ramda: `const obj = {1 : {id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, 5: {id: 5, name: 'John'}, 3: {id: 3, name: 'Peter'}}`" - compare to your result

Comment: His statement includes: I want to convert nested array of objects to this form because that way searching a name will be quick if id is given. Is this the right approach?  Using a filter is an approach option that he could consider.  Hardly worth flagging it for delete is it

Comment: Then you should make it clear that you are answering this specific part of the question and explain why it is different form the approach proposed in OP.

Comment: (1) - he asked: "Is there any other efficient way performance wise that can make the search in array quicker?" - I said "You could try.."  (2) his specific request was to find a `name` NOT an `id`.  Converting an array into a map with the id as the key does not solve the problem.  If you want to search for a name, you will still have to do something to find the name within the values on the map, so have to do at least two steps if you use the map route.  The filter method solves the problem and allows for the chance that there may be two or more people with the same name but different IDs.

Comment: yes, after the discussion here it is clear. As I mentioned above, you should make all these additinoal comments part of the answer